# how to update the value of a text in a card - Flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to change the value of the text which is the 'placeholder' in this method. But for some reason it's not updating to the new value that i wrote & retrieved from the dialog. I even tested to see what's the value of 'placeholder' and it returned the correct value/text that i wrote in the dialog but still it wasn't updated in the card.

```
Widget buildTextField(
     String subtitle, String placeholder,icon) {
    // ignore: dead_code
    return Padding(
      
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15.0),
      child:   Card(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
              color: Colors.white,
              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(100, 10, 100, 10),
              child: ListTile(
              
                title: Text(placeholder),
                subtitle: Text(subtitle),
               leading: Icon(
            icon,
            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 44, 148, 233),
            
          ),
          trailing: IconButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                final name = await openDialog(subtitle,placeholder);
              if(name == null || name.isEmpty) return;
              print(name);
              setState(() => placeholder = name);
              print(placeholder);
             //this.title: Text(placeholder);
              // setState(() {
              //   placeholder = this.name;
              // });
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.edit_outlined),
            ),         ),
                ),
              );
    
  }
  
  Future <String?>openDialog(String subtitle, String placeholder) => showDialog<String>
  (
    context: context, builder: (context)=> AlertDialog(
    title: Text(subtitle),
    content: TextField(autofocus: true,
    decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter your name'),
    controller: controller ..text = placeholder,
   // controller: controller,
    ),
    actions: [
      TextButton(onPressed: submit,
       child: Text('Save'))
    ],
  ),
  );
  void submit(){
   // Navigator.of(context).pop(controller.text);
  Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop(controller.text);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The text don't update in your card because when your `setState` rebuild your widget tree, the call to the function `buildTextField` reset it to the value passed in parameter. You can try to use a variable defined in your class instead of using an Hard coded string in your function parameter.

Here an exemple:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
  String CardText = "Name";
  String CardSubtitle = 'Card Subtitle';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(37, 57, 92, 1.0),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              buildTextField(
                  CardSubtitle, CardText, Icons.person
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildTextField(
      String subtitle, String placeholder,icon) {
    // ignore: dead_code
    return Padding(

      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15.0),
      child:   Card(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
        color: Colors.white,
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(100, 10, 100, 10),
        child: ListTile(

          title: Text(placeholder),
          subtitle: Text(subtitle),
          leading: Icon(
            icon,
            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 44, 148, 233),

          ),
          trailing: IconButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              final name = await openDialog(subtitle,placeholder);
              if(name == null || name.isEmpty) return;
              print(name);
              setState(() => CardText = name);
              print(placeholder);
              //this.title: Text(placeholder);
              // setState(() {
              //   placeholder = this.name;
              // });
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.edit_outlined),
          ),         ),
      ),
    );

  }

  Future <String?>openDialog(String subtitle, String placeholder) => showDialog<String>
    (
    context: context, builder: (context)=> AlertDialog(
    title: Text(subtitle),
    content: TextField(autofocus: true,
      decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter your name'),
      controller: controller ..text = placeholder,
      // controller: controller,
    ),
    actions: [
      TextButton(onPressed: submit,
          child: Text('Save'))
    ],
  ),
  );
  void submit(){
    // Navigator.of(context).pop(controller.text);
    Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop(controller.text);
  }

}
```

Comment: worked but what if each cardText had a different value and I used the buildTextField widget multiple times? because currently only the first Card changes its value

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your Card widget with the Builder Widget that can rebuild and update your widget

```
 Builder(
          builder: (context) {
            return Card(...);
          },
        ),
```